# Could anyone explain the print result in Python(sorry my English is poor,so please forgive me for unsuitable speaking)

Tags: python-3.x, string

The code are as follows:

```
str3 = "{{0}}"
print(str3.format("Don't print"))
```

And the result is:

```
{0}
```

I don't know why the result is not :

```
"Don't print"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `Don't print` or `"Don't print"` if it's the first then just with str3 = "{0}" will work

```
str3 = "{0}"
print(str3.format("Don't print"))
```

if is the second way you could use

```
print(str3.format("\"Don't print\""))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the proper .format() result you are looking for, you should use only one set of curly braces.  It would look like this:

```
myStr = "{0}"
print(myStr.format("Don't print"))
```

Comment: This answer is already good, but it would be a lot better if you added an explanation of *why* the doubled brackets doesn't work (escaping).